# Beach chair reclining arm mechanism

Tags: fasteners

I'm attempting to build a set of reclining beach chairs for my in-laws, but I can't identify the mechanism that's used on the arms to recline the back. Google searching hasn't been very helpful (all I can find are the chairs themselves, no parts).

Looking at the mechanism, it seems like I could fabricate one at home, but it would be pretty tedious. Does anyone know what this thing is called? Or better yet, where I can find them?

[image: One]

[image: two]

Comment: [This page](http://scarboroughmarshfurniture.com/public_html/antiquehardwaregallery.html) doesn't quite have what you're after, but they identify several types of antique reclining mechanisms that might make suitable replacements.They are called "Back racks". Maybe what you're looking for is an "arm rack"?

Comment: Interesting. I might need to look into getting some of those for a planned Morris chair.  Nothing popping up with "arm rack," unfortunately.

Comment: [This](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Convertible-furniture-hinge-recliner-hardware_60210603016.html?spm=a2700.7724857.29.165.xO1o51) might do the trick. So long as you're willing to order 1,000 of 'em. :) _No endorsement of the vendor or product implied or intended ;)_

Comment: Eesh. That's a lot of chairs.

Comment: 996 of them could be _profitttt!!!!!!_ Or... not.

Comment: You may want to consider a slightly different mechanism like [this](http://www.ana-white.com/2011/06/wood-folding-sling-chair-deck-chair-or-beach-chair-adult-size). Looks like she offers her plan freely.

Comment: Man, I really wanted to answer this. So many variations of searching for the hardware come up with just pictures of chairs. I reversed searched the images: First is boats and rigging and the second is gun stocks. Both make terrible beach chairs.

Comment: Do you have more information about the chair itself? Make and model perhaps?

Comment: @Matt, I don't. They didn't have any markings I could see. Very well made though, oak and canvas and stainless fittings.

Comment: Well this might just drive me insane. I see that it is riveted to the chair. Would be a shame if something happened to it in case there are manufacturer markings on the hidden parts....perhaps where it is just screwed on? So many sites market this chair as their own.

Comment: This has been the best source of pictures for me: http://www.sunrisechairco.com/products/beach-chair. It shows that this mechanism is built with brass and steel (from other photos). It also claims to be made in the US which could be good but still no luck ....

Comment: @Matt, those are pretty much the same chair.  A few details are different, but it's more or less the same thing.  I'll email them and see if they sell the arm racks.  If you post this as an answer, I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: If you will accept similar answers to that I can include more of the research that might help

Comment: @Matt, that's fine.  Including the background is a good idea.

Comment: @grfrazee - let us know what, if anything, you find on this! Having the link here would be most helpful.

Comment: https://www.patiofurnituresupplies.com This site may help with your search, I googled (sliding chair back hinge)... they also offer a manual adjusting system.

Comment: I too am making wood outdoor chairs. I found a site in UK that sells the ratchet and pawl recliner components but wondered if there's a site in US or Canada that sells similar. Did you find anything? https://unico.uk.com/kd-furniture-fittings/recliner-chair-fittings-outdoor-furniture/SMI000200119/pawl-for-recliner-chairs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that the hardware you are looking for is not proprietary but not easily accessible to the general public as of yet. Even if it is it is definitely not widely marketed as someone would have found it by now. My wife told me I have been looking at too many beach chairs so I have at least some credibility when it comes to this hardware availability.

Those pictures appear to be your own as looking them up got me pictures of gun stocks and boats and rigging. So... not helpful there.

**So, a lot of Googling**

In an attempt to find them I have been using the combinations of the following words:

> sliding, arm, chair, beach, lounger, hardware, brass, steel, rivet, positional, 4, four, tray (for a little bit when I though I found something similar), oak, track, channel, lock, locking, hinge. adjustable, folding, bagel

These just brought me round and round. Every corner I thought I was getting close but I was mostly going in different circles. Reverse imaging helped but again the end result was the same.

**Suppliers**

The start of forward momentum comes that this chair is apparently available through many manufacturers. Likely they are from the same template or root supplier but either way they are out there. These are the ones I found that appear unique enough. There were more but some appeared to be cookie cuttered from others. I chose the "main" ones from these groups based on how often I ran into them. In no particular order:

- [30agear.com](http://www.30agear.com/products/30a-beach-chair-with-legrest)
- [sunrisechairco.com](http://www.sunrisechairco.com/products/beach-chair-only) - This was one of the more informative ones as it claims to have sourced the parts in the US. Also it refers to the hardware in question as "rust proof brass hinges and rivets".
- [Wayfair.ca](https://www.wayfair.ca/Frankford-Umbrellas-Oak-Wood-Beach-Chair-FC101XX-FUM1049.html) - These are called Frankford Beach Chairs according to Walmart, Amazon and Wayfair.ca

They are all the same picture and therefore the same *base* product. I am sure there are minor changes between them but I can show you one and you won't be able to link it to one of those suppliers I am sure.

**Other pictures of the hardware**

If this help you or other I have found several different angles of the hardware in question. I am confident they are all the same mechanism. Some are of a different make up but the design is the same. Namely I have found some that are brass or steel by description:

All of the images have been shrunk as to not take up too much space. Should blow up fine when you click on them. I know I have another one but I need to scour my temp for it.

[image: Hinge] <sup>Image from [sunrisechairco.com](http://www.sunrisechairco.com/products/beach-chair-only)</sup>

[image: Parts description] <sup>Image from [sunrisechairco.com](http://www.sunrisechairco.com/products/beach-chair-only)</sup>

**Other options to consider**

If you are willing to break the one you have I would be curious if there were manufacture marks are the hidden sides of the hinge. The thing comes apart in at least 3 pieces.

If you are willing to contact manufacturers it is possible that one of them could get you the information your are looking for.

Comment: Bagel? You googled Bagel when looking for beach chair hardware? Either you were getting hungry, or you were testing to see if anyone actually reads your posts.

Comment: @FreeMan Ah someone noticed! I thought it would be obvious since it was on the end of the list.

Comment: Having spent a fair bit of time myself Googling on day one, I was curious to see if anyone had found an answer. It appears that "sort of" is the closest we'll get at this point.

Comment: @FreeMan It is very elusive. It looks like it is only the one chair style so possibly just the one main manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to make a T-slot on the underside that a T slides in. To lock it down you create grooves crosswise so when the armrest is pushed down it'll hold the weight.

Answer (score 1):

At least one manufacturer [calls them "rachet steamer chair" fittings](http://siso.dk/products/fittings-for-outdoor-furniture/steamer-chair-fittings/brass-fitting-f-steamer-chair--ratchet-235mm).

[image: BRASS FITTING F/STEAMER CHAIR, RATCHET 235MM]
Credit: Siso Denmark, from the link above.

Comment: Link doesn't work, but good to know they're called "steamer chair" fittings on that site.  Gives me an idea of how to make my own, at least.

Comment: I don't think those are quite it right, but they're close. The website was working for me, so I added a picture from it.

Answer (score 0):

Lee Valley sells [Ratcheting Folding Brackets](https://www.leevalley.com/en/hardware/page.aspx?p=50303&cat=3,43740,43742) that I think do what you are looking for:

[image: Bracket Image]

From their site:

> These folding brackets lock in place when lifted, and can be used for reclining chairs or folding tables. Lift again, and they release to fold down.
>
> The smaller 175mm (6.9") wide bracket has six stop positions, while the larger 245mm (9.6") wide has eight. The range of motion depends on how close they are to the pivot point, but the maximum operating arc on the small bracket is 95° from horizontal; the large has a maximum of 112°. Both will fold closed to a thickness of just over 2".

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think these are quite right.  The arm racks in my case slide past each other linearly (no hinge at one end).